# Meaning of Marginal sets and related descriptions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, verbal-subgroups

Let $F$ be a free group on a countably infinite set $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots \}$ and let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $F$. If $w = w(x_1, \ldots , x_n) \in W$ and $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ are elements of a group $G$, we define the value of the word $w$ at $(g_1, \ldots, g_n)$ to be $w(g_1, \ldots, g_n)$.

If $W$ is a non-empty set of words in $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ and $G$ is any group, a normal subgroup $N$ is said to be $W$-marginal in $G$ if, $w(g_1, \ldots, g_n) = w(u_1 g_1, \ldots , u_n g_n)$, for all $w(x_1, \ldots , x_n) \in W$, $g_i \in G$, $u_i \in N$, $1 ≤ i ≤ n$.

This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i = f_i\pmod N$, $1 ≤ i ≤ n$, always implies that $w(g_1, \ldots , g_n) = w(f_1, \ldots , f_n)$.

The following definition extends the marginality property. (suppose $W$ consists of a single word $w$. it can be extended to any $W$).

Definition 1: For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $w = w(x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ be a group word, $G$ be a group and $\bar{g} = (g_1, \ldots, g_n)$ be a tuple of elements of $G$. We say that a tuple $\bar{c} = (c_1,\ldots , c_n) \in G^n$ is a marginal tuple determined by $w$ and $\bar{g}$ if, $w(c_1g_1, \ldots, c_ng_n) = w(g_1, \ldots , g_n)$.

We will write $\bar{c} \perp w(\bar{g})$ in this case ($\bar{c}$ is a marginal tuple with respect to $w$ and $\bar{g}$). A set $\bar{C} \subseteq G^n$ is said to be marginal with respect to $w$ and $\bar{g} (\bar{C} \perp w(\bar{g}))$ if, $\bar{c} \perp w(\bar{g})$ for every tuple $\bar{c} \in \bar{C}$.

According to the above descriptions,

Q1: When we say "This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i = f_i\pmod N$, $1 ≤ i ≤ n$, always implies that $w(g_1, \ldots , g_n) = w(f_1, \ldots , f_n)$", can someone please help me to understand this more clearly?

$g_i = f_i\pmod N$ means that $g_i f_i^{-1} \in N$, right, when taking mod by a group?

When we have $w(g_1, \ldots, g_n) = w(u_1 g_1, \ldots , u_n g_n)$, then is it like, $g_i = u_i g_i \pmod G$?

Q2: According to the definition, what is meant by "The $i^{th}$ component $c_i$ of any marginal tuple $\bar{c}$ can be any element of $G$ if $w$ does not in fact depend of $x_i$?.

What is the meaning of $w$ does not in fact "depend" of $x_i$?

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. the above descriptions and definitions are from https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vitaly-Romankov/publication/332480171_An_improved_version_of_the_AAG_cryptographic_protocol/links/608646048ea909241e262a48/An-improved-version-of-the-AAG-cryptographic-protocol.pdf

Comment: Use `$x=y\pmod{N}$` for $x=y\pmod{N}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** $x\equiv y\pmod{N}$ holds if and only if $xN=yN$, if and only if there exist $n,n'\in N$ such that $x=yn$ and $xn'=y$; if and only if $Nx = Ny$; if and only if there exist $n,n'\in N$ such that $x=ny$ and $y=n'x$. In particular, if $g_i\equiv f_i\pmod{N}$, then there exist $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in N$ such that $g_iu_i=f_i$. Thus, $w(g_1,\ldots,g_n)=w(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ follows from the marginality of $N$. Conversely, if whenever $g_i\equiv f_i\pmod{N}$ we have $w(g_1,\ldots,g_n)=w(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, then for all $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in N$ we have $u_ig_i\equiv g_i\pmod{N}$, and hence $w(u_1g_1,\ldots,u_ng_n)=w(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$, proving that $N$ is $w$-marginal.

**Question 2:** The word $w$ does not "in fact depend on $x_i$" if the value of $w$ on a tuple does not depend on the value  of $x_i$. For example, consider the word $w(x,y) = xyx^{-1}$. If $G$ is abelian, then the value of $w$ at a pair of elements of $G$ does not in fact depend on $x$, since $w(a,b)=b$ for all $a,b\in G$. So the "value" of $x$ does not affect the value of $w(x,y)$. That is, the value of $w(x,y)$ does not depend on what $x$ is.

Comment: Thank you very much @ArturoMagidin . As an example, for any group $G$, if we have a group word expressed in terms of its generating elements, say $w=h_1^2 h_2^3$, where $h_1,h_2$ are the generating elements, then can we find a marginal tuple $\bar{c}=(c_1,c_2)$ such that $w(c_1 h_1, c_2 h_2) =w(h_1,h_2)$?

Comment: What requirements should be satisfied? Probably the word should be in non-reducible form to determine a marginal tuple. For the above example anyway it is non-reducible.

Comment: @Hasini: It makes no sense to talk about "group word expressed in terms of its generating elements". Group words are elements of a free group. They are not expressed in terms of generators of a group $G$. What you are talking about is the **value** of a group word in $G$. And it is irrelevant whether $h_1,h_2$ are generating elements or not, the only thing that goes into the definition is that they be elements of $G$. Having chosen fixed elements $h_1,h_2$, marginal tuples would be as you say. Whether you can find them or not will depend on your ability and on $G$. But all $e$ always works.

Comment: @Hasini: Requirements be satisfied for **what**? No, there is no requirement of "non-reducibility" or anything like that. You care about the values, not how you write down things.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ArturoMagidin If it is said as "Let $w = w(a_1, \cdots, a_k) = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k$, $a_i \in G$, $i = 1,\cdots, k$, be any expression in the straight form of a fixed element $f \in G$. It is possible that $a_i = a_j$ or $a_i = a_j^{-1}$ for $i \neq j$. Also this expression can be non-reduced.", what is meant by "in the straight form of a fixed element" and "non-reduced" here? Is it that there are no $a_i a_i^{-1}$ which can be reduced to $e$?

Comment: @Hasini: "**If** i is said"? By whom? Are you quoting something, or making it up as you go along? If you are quoting, please state from where and give full context. Otherwise, I'm going to have to say that I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes I'm quoting from https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vitaly-Romankov/publication/332480171_An_improved_version_of_the_AAG_cryptographic_protocol/links/608646048ea909241e262a48/An-improved-version-of-the-AAG-cryptographic-protocol.pdf in page numbered as 5 it is there @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @Hasini: All of that information should have been put in the post, as well as clear indication that you were copying/quoting. Otherwise, you are claiming the words as your own, i.e., plagiarizing. I don't know what htey mean by "the straight form". I've never seen that circomlocution before, and it is likely to be the result of a literal translation of some expression. Non-reduced *obviously* means that the word is not a reduced word.

Comment: I'm really sorry @ArturoMagidin I now edited the question including the link. Okay, Thank you very very much. Your answer and comments have been very much helpful to me.